# Angular material 15 2 themes with both legacy and regular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a library I created in Angular.
lately, we have upgraded our shared library to Angular 15 and with that we have changed all our imports to legacy so we keep our styles
nowadays we want to upgrade our shared library so we use the new material styling but i want my consumers to be able to use both the legacy styling and the new styling based on what they choose to use with some service/input they supply
so my main.scss looks something like this:

```
@import 'many imports';
...
@include mat.all-legacy-component-typographies();
@include mat.legacy-core();
@include apply-custom-material-theme();
```

and the apply-custom-material-theme() looks like this

```
// Custom typography
$custom-typography: mat.define-legacy-typography-config(
    $font-family: 'Assistant',
    $button:      mat.define-typography-level(14px, 30px, 700),
);


@mixin apply-custom-material-theme($theme: null) {
    $primary: mat.define-palette($primary);
    $accent:  mat.define-palette($primary, 500, 50, 50);
    $warn:    mat.define-palette($warn, 600);
    $theme:   if($theme != null, $theme, mat.define-light-theme((color: (
        primary: $primary,
        accent: $accent,
        warn: $warn)))); // allow callers to set their own theme, else fallback to default

    @include mat.all-legacy-component-themes($theme);
    @include mat.all-legacy-component-typographies($custom-typography);
    @include customize-button($theme);
    @include customize-button-toggle($theme);
```

i tried adding some if inside but then im not sure how can i control that from the component so based on some input ill be able to decide if to load the 'customize-button' from old or 'customize-button-new' from new

```
@mixin apply-custom-material-theme($theme: null, $themeVersion: 'old') {
    $primary: mat.define-palette($primary);
    $accent:  mat.define-palette($primary, 500, 50, 50);
    $warn:    mat.define-palette($warn, 600);
    $theme:   if($theme != null, $theme, mat.define-light-theme((color: (
        primary: $primary,
        accent: $accent,
        warn: $warn)))); // allow callers to set their own theme, else fallback to default

    @if $themeVersion == 'old' {
        @include mat.all-legacy-component-themes($theme);
        @include mat.all-legacy-component-typographies($custom-typography);
        @include customize-button($theme);
    } @else if $themeVersion == 'new' {
        @include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
        @include mat.all-component-typographies($custom-typography);
        @include customize-button-new($theme);
    }
    @include customize-button-toggle($theme);
```

how can I handle 2 different versions of material so I can override the material button and let the user choose if he wants the legacy version or the new version